# Onclick doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```
    <select class="input" style="width:200px">
        <option>---</option>
        <option onclick="window.location="link.php">one</option>
        <option onclick="window.location="link2.php"">two</option>
    </select>
```

It doesn't work in chrome, it work in opera/mozilla and so on. Any advice?

Comment: Yeah, don't use the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Everytime someone uses --- as an option, a UI designer gets a heart attack. Use optgroup, please.

Comment: @WTP How does `optgroup` help me to have an empty default option?

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<select class="input" onchange="window.location.href = this.value" style="width:200px">
        <option>---</option>
        <option value="link.php">one</option>
        <option value="link2.php">two</option>
    </select>
```

I know its not EXACTLY the same... but having a click event on the option of a select list is not good practice.  Instead of onchange, you could have onclick as well... but onchange really is the way to do this, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the safest approach is to use the onchange event of the select element, and use its value to determine the action to take. I don't think onclick works for option in IE, either.

Answer (score 3):

Are the double quotes inside the onclick attributes not meant to be single quotes ?

Comment: @Radek S: One thing I can think of is parser leniency (read: smartassery).

Comment: @BoltClock I can't really believe that Gecko is smarter than WebKit. Oh well, maybe it is. :)

Comment: @Radek.  You're right, I typed a quick example with the quotes rights and it's like hey says. Works in FF, not in chrome.  Thx for pointing this out.  And Zoidberg's solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick isn't going to work the way you're trying to get it to work, and you're going to have to account for differences in how the browsers deal with the `select` object. I would advise that you use the onchange event on the `select` object, then test for the selected option. Note that these events fire differently on different browsers.