# Trying to create/bind onClick event to <option> generated through a dojo.xhrGet request

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

I'm trying to make a piece of dojo Code work and having a bit of a hard time.
The intention behind it goes like this:

1- Have a select fire an onChange event that retrieves a list of options through dojo.xhrGet. 
2- Have each one of the options retrieved get its own onclick event associated/binded to it and the function that it fires takes 2 arguments

Problem: At this point the onClick event on the options fires as soon as it is retrieved through Ajax and doesn't pass the firt argument. The events stop firing after that (a click produces nothing).

Thank you for your feedback in advance. The Code follows

JS

```
function checkAvailable(i){
    var id_prog = 'programa_'+i;
    var id_coreo = 'coreografia_'+i;

    var prog = dojo.byId(id_prog).value;

    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"ajaxCoreo.php",
        handleAs:"text",
        content: {
            programa: prog,
            item: i
        }, 
        load: function(data){
            var targetNode = dojo.byId(id_coreo);
            dojo.place(data,targetNode,"only");
            dojo.byId(id_coreo).disabled = false;
            var callback = function(evt){
                var j = evt.target.innerHTML;

                checkPack(j,i);
                console.log('write me if you fire inside first function');
            };
            dojo.query("#coreografia_1>option").connect('click', callback);
            setValor(i);
        }

    });

}



    function checkPack(j,i){
    console.log('write me if you fire inside second function');
    console.log(j);
    console.log(i);

    var num = j;
    var id_prog = 'programa_'+i;
    var id_coreo = 'coreografia_'+j;

    var prog = dojo.byId(id_prog).value;

    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"ajaxPack.php",
        handleAs:"text",
        content: {
            programa: prog,
            coreo: j
        },
        load: function(data){

            if(data=="true"){
                dojo.query("option[value="+num+"]").forEach(dojo.destroy);
                alert('O Pack escolhido já foi encomendado previamente.');
                setValor(i);
            }

        }

    });

}
```

HTML

```
<select name="programa[]" id="programa_1" onChange="checkAvailable(1)" title="obrigatorio">
                <option value="0">Choose your program</option> 

</select>
 <select name="coreografia_1" id="coreografia_1" disabled="disabled" title="obrigatorio">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Escolha Um Programa</option> //this is the node that is populated by the first xhrGet call
            </select>
```

EDIT: I've edited the code to reflect the changes to it and added the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, if you spend more than 1 day trying to track a cross-brower issue it's probably somewhere on your basic html knowledge or your basic Js concepts.

This one was related to the fact that only FF manages onclick events directly attached to option tag. For the rest of the gang you need to attach the onchange to the  parent.

So here is the final version of the working code, in case anyone comes upon a similar issue

```
function checkAvailable(i){
    var id_prog = 'programa_'+i;
    var id_coreo = 'coreografia_'+i;

    var prog = dojo.byId(id_prog).value;

    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"ajaxCoreo.php",
        handleAs:"text",
        content: {
            programa: prog,
            item: i
        }, 
        load: function(data){
            var targetNode = dojo.byId(id_coreo);
            dojo.place(data,targetNode,"only");
            dojo.byId(id_coreo).disabled = false;
            var callback = function(evt){
                var j = evt.target.value;
                checkPack(j,i);
            };
            dojo.query("#coreografia_"+i).connect('onchange', callback);
            setValor(i);
        }

    });

}



    function checkPack(j,i){
    console.log('write me if you fire inside second function');
    console.log(j);
    console.log(i);

    var num = j;
    var id_prog = 'programa_'+i;
    var id_coreo = 'coreografia_'+j;

    var prog = dojo.byId(id_prog).value;

    //Confirma Se não há encomendas previas deste pack (um máximo de 2 anteriores)

    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"ajaxPack.php",
        handleAs:"text",
        content: {
            programa: prog,
            coreo: j
        },
        load: function(data){

            if(data=="true"){
                dojo.query("#coreografia_"+i+" option[value="+num+"]").forEach(dojo.destroy);
                alert('O Pack escolhido já foi encomendado previamente.');

            }

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting your code, i can see that in the function **checkAvailable**, in the line where you connect to *onclick* event instead of passing the  function as *callback* you are *calling* it.

```
dojo.connect(opt,'onclick', checkPack(opt.target.innerHTML,i));
```

You should do something like this:

```
var callback = function(){
    checkPack(opt.target.innerHTML,i);
};
dojo.connect(opt,'onclick', callback);
```

Comment: This works to fix part of the problem. The question now is Chrome. It works for FF, but Chrome never fires the registered checkPack function. Nothing on the console either. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Script works on FF and IE9. Doesn't work for Chrome, Safari and IE below 9. By working I mean, it does fire the first xhrGet function, retrieves and populates de content desired and I believe (by inspecting the DOM) that it does register a click event associated with each <option>. Not working means it never actually fires that registered function.

Comment: I've Edited the code to reflect Juanma's input and the html. Im sort of convinced its a Event management problem but Im running out of "tries"...

Comment: I have found the solution based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome