# Show or hide an element using javascript in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the html code..

```
<select id="dept" name="dept" style="float: left;">
        <option value="eee" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">EEE</option>
        <option value="ece" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">ECE</option>
        <option value="eie" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">EIE</option>
        <option value="cse" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">CSE</option>
        <option value="it" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">IT</option>
        <option value="mechanical" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Mechanical</option>
        <option value="civil" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Civil</option>
        <option value="mechatronics" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Mechatronics</option>
        <option value="biotech" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Bio-tech</option>
        <option value="automobile" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Automobile</option>
        <option value="chemical" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Chemical</option>
        <option value="aeronautical" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Aeronautical</option>
        <option value="architecture" onclick="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 0)">Architecture</option>
        <option value="others" onclick="javascript:toggleDisplay('dept_input_div', 1);">Others..</option>
      </select>
      <div id="dept_input_div" style="display: none">
      <input class="inputbox" name="dept-input" type="text" id="dept-inputbox" />
      </div>
```

Here is the javascript code..

```
    function toggleDisplay(id, displayvalue)
{
    if ( displayvalue == 1 ) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    } else if ( displayvalue == 0 ) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine in firefox and ie (compatibility view turned off) but in chrome and ie(compatibility turned on).

What am i doing wrong? Is there a proper way of doing this that works in all browsers?

Comment: jQuery would abstract browser differences...

Comment: Relying on "click" events for `<option>` elements is pretty flaky.  You should set up a "change" handler for the `<select>` instead.

Comment: Also specify displayvalue = 0 inside displayvalue == 1 <if block>.

Comment: Also repeating code like that is really terrible. Computers are pretty good at stuff like that.

Comment: onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome

Answer (score 2):

use onchange instead of onclick    
**html**

```
<select id="dept" name="dept" style="float: left;" onchange="toggleDisplay('dept_input_div' , this.value)">
            <option value="eee" >EEE</option>
            <option value="ece" >ECE</option>
            <option value="eie" >EIE</option>
            <option value="cse" >CSE</option>
            <option value="it" >IT</option>
            <option value="mechanical" >Mechanical</option>
            <option value="civil" >Civil</option>
            <option value="mechatronics" >Mechatronics</option>
            <option value="biotech" >Bio-tech</option>
            <option value="automobile" >Automobile</option>
            <option value="chemical" >Chemical</option>
            <option value="aeronautical" >Aeronautical</option>
            <option value="architecture" >Architecture</option>
            <option value="others">Others..</option>
</select>
<div id="dept_input_div" style="display: none">
      <input class="inputbox" name="dept-input" type="text" id="dept-inputbox" />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function toggleDisplay(id, displayvalue)
{    
    if ( displayvalue == "others" ) {
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```