# Conditional Combination Multiple radio buttons to show/hide

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form that reveals extra options when posting option is selected.
However what I really want it to do is reveal these options only when a combination of choices are made from previous very similar set of radio buttons.
So in total have 3 sets of radio buttons. 1. uk or abroad posting, 2.payment by card, account or cash, 3. posting options, which you can see below.
The extra hidden posting option should be revealed ONLY when customer choices Uk for destination,AND payment is by (card OR account) AND need posting.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .show { display: block;  }
    .hide { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSelect() {
        var select = document.getElementById('my_select');
        select.className = 'show';
    }
</script>


<div id="post">
    <fieldset class="post" > 
        <legend>
            <span class="wrap3">&nbsp;Please choose method of delivery &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </legend> 

        <ul class="radio"> 
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="Postage_Method" id="post"  value="Post"  onclick="showSelect();"/>
                <label for="post">&nbsp;Please Post</label>
            </li> 

            <select id="my_select" class="hide">
                <option value="nxday">Next Day Monday to Friday </option>
                <option value="b9">Before 9 a.m. Monday to Friday </option>
                <option value="b10">Before 10 a.m. Monday to Friday </option>
                <option value="b12">Before 12 a.m. Monday to Friday </option>
                <option value="sat9">Saturday Before 9 a.m.  </option>
                <option value="sat10">Saturday Before 10 a.m. </option>
            </select>


            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="Postage_Method" id="post" value="Arrange Own Pick Up " />
                <label for="own">&nbsp;Will arrange own pick up</label>
            </li> 

            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="Postage_Method" id="post" value="Collect in person" />
                <label for="collect">&nbsp;Will collect in person</label>
            </li> 
        </ul> 
    </fieldset> 
</div>
```

Comment: You know the one thing I hate more than unindented code? **inconsistently** indented code. Fix your indentation, [edit] your post, maybe then I'll be able to provide an answer. Right now, your code is extremely unreadable.

Comment: Please note an invalid tag `</uk>` and multiple use of IDs `pay` & `post`. Also, form has not ending tag.

Comment: I just formated the indentations, dunno why you have a <select> there floating inside the <ul> element but not within any <li>

Comment: The part in between <select> and </select> is the hidden options.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you want something similar to this: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/AtamevO/1)

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208836/show-or-hide-an-element-using-javascript-in-all-browsers)

I modify your code instead of using onclick, use onchage

**Updated**
Have you try to use checkbox instead?
I did a modification to your code using checkbox. Hope this is the combination you are asking. [Demo2](http://jsbin.com/AtamevO/2)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want eventually to happen but ONLY WHEN the previous right combination of radio buttons has been chosen. I have two other sets of buttons.

Comment: Which is the combination?

Comment: Hi Diego. thanks for your reply. The problem I have is that there are two other sets of radio buttons and the display of the 3rd and last hidden extra options depends only if the user has chosen uk option from first set and either 'payment by card' or 'on account' from the 2nd set of options. Can you help please.

Comment: I don't see the UK radio buttons you are talking about, include them.