# Rendering blade template base on Javascript Condition

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

## I have

an account > index page with a table, and other modals, that I slice into a small blade views. On that page, I have 100000 accounts.

## Problem

There is a section of PHP on top of my edit modal that is making 100000 curls requests, and cause a huge delay on my account > index page.

## My goal

is to prevent rendering those blades right up front and only render if the user click on the Pencil icon.

[image]

---

Here is my  **account.index blade**

```
@extends('layouts.internal.master')
    @section('content')

    

    <div class="panel account-panel" style="padding: 30px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
    
       
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <a id="account-create" class="btn btn-success btn-block mb20" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".account-create">Create</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
          <table class="table" id="account-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Account ID</th>
                <th>Customer Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th class="text-center">Auto Provisioning</th>
                <th class="text-center">AP</th>
                <th style="min-width: 90px;">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    
              <?php
              $x = 0;
    
              ?>
              @foreach( $accounts as $account )
    
              @if($account->email_address !== 'admin@benunets.com')
          
              <tr>
                <td>{{$x += 1 }}</td>
                <td><a href="/account/{!! $account->account_id !!}">{!! $account->account_id !!}</a></td>
                <td>
    
                {{-- <img src="{{ $image }}" width="30px"> --}}
    
                <span class="badge" style="background-color: {{ $color2 }}">{!! $customer_type !!}</span></td>
                <td>{!! ucfirst($account->first_name) !!} {!! ucfirst($account->last_name) !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $account->email_address !!}</td>
                <td class="text-center" >
    
                  @if($user != null AND $user->auto_provisioning == 1)
                  {!! Helper::intBoolToIcon($user->auto_provisioning) !!}
                  @else
                  <i title="false" style="font-size: 18px; color: #F44336" class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  @endif
    
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" ><b>{!! $count_cpe !!}</b></td>
                <td class="text-center">
    
                  <!-- Buttons -->
                  <div class="tool-buttons">
                    <ul class="button-list">
    
                      <!-- Edit -->
                      <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".account-edit-{!! $account->account_id !!}" class="tooltips account-edit" data-id="{!! $account->account_id !!}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></li>
    
                      <!-- Delete -->
                      <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".account-destroy-{!! $account->account_id !!}" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
    
                </td>
              </tr>
    
              @endif
              @endforeach
    
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    @include('account.modal.account.destroy')
    @include('account.modal.account.create')
    @include('account.modal.account.edit')


@section('pagescripts')

<script type="text/javascript">


  /*=============================================================================================
  =            Edit            =
  ============================*/


  //Edit Mode
  $('.account-edit').click( function() {


    var id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(id);

    //Style
    var val2 = $("#auto_provisioning_switch-"+id).val();

    //Set the AP switch
    if(val2 == 1){
      $("#auto_provisioning_switch-"+id).bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
      $("[name='auto_provisioning_switch']").val(1);
      $('#service_plan_div-'+id).show();

      // Set the service plan dd menu
      var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/account/'+id+'/service_plan'});
      ajax.done(function (service_plan) {
        console.log(service_plan+' | id : ' + id );
        $('#service_plan-'+id).val(service_plan);
        });

    }else{
      $("#auto_provisioning_switch-"+id).bootstrapSwitch('state', false);
      $("[name='auto_provisioning_switch']").val(0);
      $('#service_plan_div-'+id).hide();
    }

    
  });

  




</script>

@stop
```

---

I only want to render

`@include('account.modal.account.edit')`

when I clicked on the **pencil** to edit.

## OR

`@include('account.modal.account.destroy')`

when I clicked on the **trash** to delete.

---

**How do I do that ?**

---

Any hints on how to prevent that will be a huge help !!!

Comment: JS? you mean javascript? I don't see any javascript in your code. any - If I understand correctly - then its not possible. the @include directive is happening during rendering in the server, and the javascript happens in the browser after the rendered page reaches the client.

Comment: I was trying to show less codes but I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cause the blade rendering to change with javascript code becuase the blade rendering is happening on your server and the javascript is happening on your browser.

What you CAN do is add javascript that hides the sections when a user interacts with your page.

[Show or hide an element using javascript in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208836/show-or-hide-an-element-using-javascript-in-all-browsers)

Comment: In that case, there are PHP on top of my edit modal, how do I avoid executing it ? I have 10000 accounts and it's making 10000 curls requests cause a huge delay :( ... Any hints on how to prevent that will be a huge help !!!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Maybe the solution for you is....more blades/pages? Is this the flow you want: User navigates to main page, clicks on pencil and then the browser navigates to a different "edit" page? In the "edit page" you will only have the @include('account.modal.account.edit') directive.

Comment: I wish I have that option, then I wouldn't ask this question. I can't do redirect, I am dealing with a modal right now.

Comment: So your flow is : user requests once, makes the server work really hard, gets all the data on the first response. Nothing your client will do can make time go backwards and prevent your server from doing what it already did. Either I'm not understanding your question or you have a giant hole in your understanding of browser-server communication.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't have done that - putting a lot of weigh to my server right up front. But I am working on improving it now. I should convert it to an ajax GET to get a certain account info base on account ID, when the user click on the pencil icon. I was wondering - maybe there is another way, but I guest NOT.