# Google Chrome's bug onclick of <select> elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, click

HTML:

```
<select id="page">
   <option value="none">--</option>
   <option id="about" value="about">About</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('about').onclick = function(){
    alert('normal onclick');
}
$("#about").click(function(){
    alert("jquery click")
});
```

None of them work on Chrome, and seems like Chrome only

What's happening?

Here goes the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9ZK3/2/

Comment: I don't think you can add a click handler to an `<option>` for Chrome. Fairly sure I read this somewhere. Will try to find reference.

Comment: is it happening to Chrome only?

Comment: Your code works in IE9

Comment: I'm a big fan of google :(... so heart breaking

Comment: Old article, but I found it http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html - although their demo has a working `onclick` for Chrome...

Comment: Good stuffs, thanks... I guess I just check the value of the select itself onclick

Comment: possible duplicate of [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Comment: sorry, I'm just curious: why do you need onClick for option instead of onChange for select?

Answer (score 3):

Put an event handler on the `select` element instead of `option`, and it will work in all browsers. Use the `change` and `keyup` events:

```
$('#page').on( 'change keyup', function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    if( selected == 'about' )
        alert( 'About!' );
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/S9ZK3/3/)

Why both the `change` and `keyup` events? The `change` event handles mouse interaction, and the `keyup` makes the selector respond when you use the arrow keys or other keys to navigate up and down in the selector.

Alternatively, you can leave out `keyup` and only listen for the `change` event. Then if you open the selector and use the cursor keys to navigate up and down, nothing will happen until you hit Enter. That will fire a `change` event.

In many cases it's more helpful to give immediate feedback to the user while navigating up and down through the list with the keyboard, and listening to `change keyup` does that.

Why `change` instead of `click`? You could use either, but the `click` event fires on any click, even if the value hasn't actually changed. OTOH, you may *want* the event to fire even if the user just clicks on the already-selected option, so in that case the `click` event would be better.

Actually, after testing it a bit more, there's a bit more to the `click` vs. `change` question. Normal mouse interaction with a select list allows for two slightly different ways of using it:

1. Press the mouse on the selector, keep it pressed down, roll it over an option, and finally release it.
2. Press the mouse on the selector *and release it*. The selector opens to show the options. Roll the mouse over the options (the button is not down at this time), and finally click the button on an option.

If you listen for the `click` event instead of `change`, then in case #2 the event fires twice, on the initial click and on the final click that selects an option. So you could use `click` or `change` depending on whether you want both clicks or just the final option selection.

I have to add that I haven't tested `click` thoroughly here, but I have tested `change` and `change keyup` very thoroughly, so I trust those more.

Comment: ... please read the above comments, i'm not asking how to do it... i'm asking is this a bug or not... And somehow I don't have enough reputation to vote down @_o

Comment: Michael, are you sure `change` event is not fired when option is selected using keyboard?

Comment: "Good stuffs, thanks... I guess I just check the value of the select itself onclick" -> it was one of my comments

Comment: @yefrem - I added some detail about the events. The `change` event is not fired when you use the cursor keys or alphanumeric keys to navigate through the list. `change` is fired when you finally hit the Enter key. Keyboard navigation does fire the `keyup` event, so you can use that to make the selection more responsive when that is appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelGeary thanks for clarification, I never added `keyup` listener for dropdowns so your comment made me a little scared. I just checked: when user activates dropdown using TAB and then selects option using arrows `select` event is fired only after dropdown loses focus (TAB pressed once more) so it's really a good idea to add `keyup` listener. Thanks for advice.