# JavaScript functions run from local machine, but not from server

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am writing a script that will show/hide cascading lists as options are selected from each of four pull-down menus. For example, when a person chooses a state, it hides the default empty list of cities, and shows instead the appropriate city list for that state.

Here is a simplified version of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mapselector3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mapselectorstyles3.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="reset('selectstate')">
        <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Device Installation</h1>
        <p>Select a specific printer by location:</p>
        <form name="mapselector">


            <div class="selectholder">
            <label>Select State:</label>

            <!--states list-->
            <select id="stateselector">
                <option class="selectstate" selected="selected" >Select a State</option>
                <option onclick='showCities("mn")'>Minnesota</option>
                <option onclick='showCities("tx")'>Texas</option>
                <option onclick='showCities("ca")'>California</option>
            </select>

            </div>

            <div class="selectholder">
            <label>Select City:</label>

            <!--cities default list-->
            <select id="cityselector">
                <option>City</option>
            </select>


            <!--cities options-->
            <select id="mn" class="hidden">
                <option  class="selectcity" selected="selected">Then a City</option>
                <option onclick='showBuildings("mn-maplewood")'>Maplewood</option>

            </select>


            </div>

            <div class="selectholder">
            <label>Select Building:</label>

            <!--Building default list-->
            <select id="buildingselector">
                <option>Building</option>
            </select>


            <!--MN buildings options-->
            <select id="mn-maplewood" class="hidden">
                <option  class="selectbuilding" selected="selected">Then a Building</option>
                <option onclick='showFloors("mn-maplewood-b224")'>Building 224</option>
                <option onclick='showFloors("mn-maplewood-b220")'>Building 220</option>
                <option onclick='showFloors("mn-maplewood-b223")'>Building 223</option>
            </select>


            </div>

            <div class="selectholder">
            <label>Select Floor:</label>

            <!--Floors default list-->
            <select id="floorselector" name="floorselector">
                <option>Floor</option>
            </select>


            <!--MN-maplewood floors lists-->
            <select id="mn-maplewood-b224" class='hidden'>
                <option  class="selectfloor" selected="selected">Then a Floor</option>
                <option onclick='setButtonPath("states/mncities/maplewoodbuildings/224floors/us-mn-maplewood-b224-floor1.htm")'>Floor 1</option>
                <option onclick='setButtonPath("states/mncities/maplewoodbuildings/224floors/us-mn-maplewood-b224-floor2.htm")'>Floor 2</option>
                <option onclick='setButtonPath("states/mncities/maplewoodbuildings/224floors/us-mn-maplewood-b224-floor3.htm")'>Floor 3</option>
            </select>



            </div>


            <a id="submit" href="mapselector3.htm"><div id="button">Floor Map</div></a>
        </form>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <div id="currentstate"></div>
        <div id="currentcity"></div>
        <div id="currentbuilding"></div>
        <div id="currentfloor"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've pared it down to one option, but my lists will include about 25 states, and a varying number of cities per state, buildings per city, and floors per building. I've generated all the lists in the HTML and hidden them off screen with CSS, and my JavaScript is intended to swap in the appropriate lists when an option is clicked.

Here's what my script looks like:

```
var currentState = 'cityselector';
var currentCity = 'buildingselector';
var currentBuilding = 'floorselector';

function reset(selector) {
    var reset = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    for(i=0; i<reset.length; i++) {
        reset[i].selected = "selected";
    }
}

function hide(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).className = "hidden";
}

function show(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).className = "shown";
}

function showCities(stateName) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'in showCities()';
    //hide the current selections and reset the lists to show "Then a City"
    hide(currentState);
    hide(currentCity);
    hide(currentBuilding);
    reset('selectcity');

    //set the currentState to the value clicked and reset currentCity and currentBuilding to their original defaults
    currentState = stateName;
    currentCity = 'buildingselector';
    currentBuilding = 'floorselector';

    //rebuild the list
    show(stateName);
    show(currentCity);
    show(currentBuilding);
    document.getElementById('currentstate').innerHTML = 'currentState = ' + currentState;
}

function showBuildings(cityName) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'in showBuildings()';
    //hide the current selections and reset the lists to show "Then a Building"
    hide(currentCity);
    hide(currentBuilding);
    reset('selectbuilding');

    //set the currentCity to the value clicked and reset currentBuilding to its' original default
    currentCity = cityName;
    currentBuilding = 'floorselector';

    //rebuild the list
    show(cityName);
    show(currentBuilding);
    document.getElementById('currentbuilding').innerHTML = 'currentBuilding = ' + cityName;
}

function showFloors(building) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'in showFloors()';
    //hide the current selections and reset the lists to show "Then a Floor"
    hide(currentBuilding);
    reset('selectfloor');

    //set the currentBuilding to the value clicked
    currentBuilding = building;

    //rebuild the list
    show(building);
}

function setButtonPath(path) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'in setButtonPath()';
    submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    submitButton.href = path;
}
```

The script functions exactly as expected when run in IE from my local hard disk, but when I save the file to a shared network folder within our domain and run it from there, the script doesn't run (except the `<body onload="reset('selectstate')">`. I've tried rewriting the entire thing with Jquery, and ran into the same problem. It WILL work in Firefox and Chrome, and I was unable to find any errors with Firebug, but I need this to be usable in IE. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of setting the `onclick` for all `<option>` elements, you should use the `onchange` for the `<select>` element and check the current `.value` of the element. That wouldn't fix your problem, but it's something I noticed

Comment: ahh, that's a good idea, that'll definitely simplify my HTML, thanks! But yeah still not gonna fix my issue...

Comment: Also, `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't supported before IE 9 (in case you're testing the live version with that) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName , http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: Also, what exactly "doesn't run"? Do none of the events trigger anymore?

Comment: I'm only concerned about supporting IE9 and IE10, so previous version support is not an issue.

Comment: My reset(element) function runs from the body onload event handler, but none of my onclick functions ever run at all. I have test divs at the end of my page to indicate when I have entered the functions, and those tests are not triggered.

Comment: @user2379380 Ian's suggestion would solve your problem. As I thought, IE (and others) don't support the onclick on option elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome

Comment: wow, I had no idea. I'll give that a shot and let you know how it turns out. Thank you!!

Comment: @Ian I implemented the onchange handler on my select elements to replace the onclick handler on my option elements, and now it works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2379380 Cool, glad that helped :) I added an answer for the heck of it