# Ng-click built inside Ng-Repeat - not fires its function in chrome, works in FF

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

This code works great with FF.
It fires up the updateModels funcion.

But, In Chrome it doesn't do anything....

```
$scope.updateModels = function(model_id,option_txt,option_idx){
console.log('do something');
};



 <div class="span10" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <h1>Models Switcher:</h1>
 <div id="models-container">
 <div class="span3 .model-generic" ng-repeat="model in models">
 <select class="span9" id="model-{{model.idx}}" ng-model="models">
 <option ng-repeat="option in model track by $id($index)" value="{{option.opt_price}}" data-ng- click="$parent.updateModels(model.idx,option)" >
{{option.opt_title}}
 </option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Chrome does not fire a click event for `<option>`s. See [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Would an [ng-change](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange) on the `<select>` not do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in IE (from 10), FF, Chrome:

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="o.id as o.id for o in list" ng-change="onFunction(item)">{{item}}</select>
```

where item list is in the form:

```
$scope.list = [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5}];
```