# Javascript Calculation issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this function but i have issue with it.

```
function calc(id)
{
var price = document.getElementById("hidden-output-"+id);
var amount = document.getElementById("input-"+id);

if(price.value=="")
{
price.value = 0;
}
if(b.value=="")
{
amount.value = 1;
}

var total = amount.value * price.value;
document.getElementById("output-"+id).value=total;
}
```

It's not working and I don't know why I am new to javascript.

This is the HTML and PHP

```
<?php




foreach($category->fetch_category() as $data){

    $id = $data->id;

    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo"<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$data->id\" />";
    echo"<p><strong>".$data->cat_name."</strong></p>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";


    echo"<select>";
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $product)
    {
        $price = $product->price;
    echo"<option value = $product->id onclick=\"UpdateRecord($product->id,$data->id)\">$product->p_name</option>";
    }
    echo"</select>";

    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";

    echo"<td>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo"<input class=\"input-mini\" id=input-$data->id onkeyup=\"calc($data->id)\" type=\"text\" value=\"1\"/>";
    echo"<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"$product->id\" value=\"$product->quantity\" />";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products->fetch_products($id) as $pricer){
    if ($i==1) break;    

    echo"<td>";

    echo"<center>";
    echo("<div id=\"output-$data->id\" ><p>$pricer->price</p></div>");
    echo"<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hidden-output-$data->id\" value=\"$pricer->price\"/>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</td>";
    $i++;
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}

?>
```

I am triyng to calculate the price of each field amount * price then to SUM all price fields and display result in

```
<td>Total : <input class="span1" type="text" id="total_calc" readonly="true" /></td>
```

I also tried these variants :

```
function calc3(id) {

   var price = document.getElementById('hidden-output-'+id);
   var numberField = document.getElementById('input-'+id);
   numberField.onkeyup = numberField.onpaste = function() {
      if(this.value.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('output-'+id).innerHTML = '';
         return;
      }
      var number = parseInt(this.value);
      if(isNaN(number)) return;
      document.getElementById('output-'+id).innerHTML = number * price;
   };
   numberField.onkeyup(); 
};

// This one always return NaN
```

This is the project :
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34473mp&s=5

Comment: options do not have onclick, use onchange on the select and read the value.

Comment: These are two different functions onclick ="UpdateRecord" not calc()

Comment: Have you tested this in IE? [Hence my comment above...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(b.value=="")
{
  amount.value = 1;
}
```

What is `b.value` in your `calc` function. This is not `defined` that is why throws error and script is not executed.

In your `calc3` function. You need to modify following line

`if(isNaN(number)) return;` to  `number = isNaN(number) ? 0 : number`

Comment: I fixed it no change... now is if(amount.value=="")

Comment: I changed it to number = isNaN(number) ? 0 : number; same NaN