# Alert can't be called in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, select

I met an error when i use chrome (it's ok in firefox).
It's my code, very simple:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<select>
        <option onclick="alert('abc');">A</option>
        <option>B</option>
</select>         
</body>
</html>
```

In firefox, when i click on option A, it will be show an alert('abc'). But in chrome, it doesn't run. Can i change something in setting of chrome?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use `onchange` on the select, and filter by the selected option. Better yet, attach the handler unobtrusively.

Comment: review this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome

Answer (score 2):

use onchange event provided by html select,

### Example : alerts the selected option

```
<select onchange="alert(this.value)">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `onchange` event

http://jsfiddle.net/WB3Q9/

When a user selects an option, the value of the select element changes, thus firing the `onchange` event and whatever function you binded to it

`<select onchange="alert('The Value is ' + this.value)">`