# Hiding child of another parent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML

```
<div>
    <div id='a'>
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <select>
        <option id='Hello'>Hello</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now when i select any option in `<select>`,the `<ul>` tag should get hidden.

I tired below but it does not seem to work.

```
 $('#Hello').click(function () {
     $(this).closest('#a').find('ul').css('display', 'none');
 });
```

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/v2p4bvuo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to listen `onchange` event on selectbox, option `onclick` is not reliable. Then you need to find previous element using [`$.fn.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) not `closest`:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $(this).prev('#a').find('ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Since OP is using ID so `$('#a').find('ul').hide();` had done the trick

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the event(change instead of click) to select element and check if selected option has required id, if yes the hide the required ul:

```
 $('select').change(function () {
   $(this).prev().find('ul').toggle($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')!="Hello");
 }).change();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pccmtav5/)**

Comment: Note that the [`click` event on many browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome) will fail to work on `<option>` tags.  Better to do it on the `<select>`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Or possibly better even, use the change event.

Comment: There can be multiple option,so i can bind it to 1 id

Comment: @Richa: do these elements have common class,value,text or attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `.hide()` instead of `.css()` and use `change` event on select element:

```
$('#Hello').on("change", function () {
     $(this).closest('#a').find('ul').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply the following?

`$("select").change(function() {
    $("#a ul").hide();
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div>
        <div id='a'>
            <ul>
                <li data-link="link_a">a</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <select>
            <option value='link_a'>Hello</option>
        </select>
    </div>


$('#Hello').click(function () {
   $('a[data-link="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add any `jquery.min.js` & then put below script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").click(function() {
    $("#a ul").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```