# Hide elements in second <select> list

Tags: javascript, html

On my page, there are two dropdown lists. What I want to do is hide an  element in one list if the mirroring option is selected in the other list. It's pretty much running exactly how I want it right now, except for the fact that it hides elements in its own list and not the other list.

I tried switching the variables in the final two if statements, but that just made the options vanish forever.
I've got no idea whats wrong.

```js
//hidden element in dropdown list 1
var option_to_hide1;
//hidden element in dropdown list 2
var option_to_hide2;

function option_hide(list) {
  //grab the team selected by the user in the dropdown list
  var team_selected = document.getElementById("team_compare" + list).value;

  //if an element is currently hidden, unhide it
  if (typeof(option_to_hide1) != "undefined" && option_to_hide1 !== null && list == 2) {
    option_to_hide1.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (typeof(option_to_hide2) != "undefined" && option_to_hide2 !== null && list == 1) {
    option_to_hide2.style.display = 'block';
  }
  //select the element to hide and then hide it
  if (list == 1) {
    option_to_hide2 = document.getElementById(team_selected + list);
    option_to_hide2.style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (list == 2) {
    option_to_hide1 = document.getElementById(team_selected + list);
    option_to_hide1.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="compare_form">
  <form action="">
    <select name="team_compare1" id="team_compare1">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please select a team...</option>
      <option id="DP1" value="DP" onclick="option_hide(1)">DP</option>
      <option id="NiP1" value="NiP" onclick="option_hide(1)">NiP</option>
      <option id="Portugal1" value="Portugal" onclick="option_hide(1)">Portugal</option>
      <option id="Serbia1" value="Serbia" onclick="option_hide(1)">Serbia</option>
      <option id="VG1" value="VG" onclick="option_hide(1)">VG</option>
    </select>
    <select name="team_compare2" id="team_compare2">
      <option option value="" disabled selected>Please select a team...</option>
      <option id="DP2" value="DP" onclick="option_hide(2)">DP</option>
      <option id="NiP2" value="NiP" onclick="option_hide(2)">NiP</option>
      <option id="Portugal2" value="Portugal" onclick="option_hide(2)">Portugal</option>
      <option id="Serbia2" value="Serbia" onclick="option_hide(2)">Serbia</option>
      <option id="VG2" value="VG" onclick="option_hide(2)">VG</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle with my code illustrating the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/3dv89anj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to remove `onclick="option_hide(1)"` on your option elements. `Onclick` on option tag doesn't [seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome) on other browsers. 
Instead of `onclick` use `onchange` on `select` tag.

e.g.

`<select name="team_compare1" id="team_compare1" onchange="option_hide(1)">`

The problem is you're hiding the option on your selected dropdown because you're targeting the element based on what's your selected list instead of the opposite one.

**This one :**

```
if (list == 1) {
    // since list = 1, then it will hide the element on list1
    option_to_hide2 = document.getElementById(team_selected + list);
    option_to_hide2.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**You have to change that to :**

```
if (list == 1) {
    option_to_hide2 = document.getElementById(team_selected + 2);
    option_to_hide2.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaz24h2f/)