# How to kill this unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some french texts which is using single quote and double quote in select items option as function parameter.

```
  $.get(submit_url + '/spelist', {
      action: 'spelist',
      list: 'a'
  }, function(msg) {
    $('#ac1').html('');
    for(be in msg.db) {
      var part_one = msg.db[be].id;
      var part_two = msg.db[be].list;
      $('#ac1').append('<option  style="padding:10px 0px;" onclick="button_5a1_list_submit(' + part_one + ',\'' + part_two + '\');">' + part_two + '</option>');       
    }
  });
```

which is creating as below:

```
onclick="button_5a1_list_submit(20, 'value has single quote 'again text');"
```

But the single quote or double quote is causing unexpected identifier how do you kill this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would instead bind an `.on('click')` to the options, that should solve your problem.

Comment: JSON.stringify to turn any old toothpick mess into valid js string literals, switch the attrib delims to apos

Comment: can you use onclick on <options>? how would that work in mobile?

Comment: How to do the .on('click') with JavaScript ? @sharf

Comment: Do you not want the jQuery method?

Comment: You can't bind events to `<option>` tag at all ... not supported by many browsers ... IE for example

Comment: @charlietfl according to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#handler-onclick) all elements support `onClick`, I just can't think of any browser that would render the option so that it can be clicked.

Comment: @sharf see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome

Comment: @charlietfl Seems FIreFox is the odd duck for once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most browsers won't support `onClick` for an option anyway, you'll need to bind to the `select` element.

What I suggest is adding a `data` attribute to your option such as:

```
$("#ac1").append("<option data-val=\""+part_one+"\">"+part_two+"</option>");
```

and binding to the `select` like this:

```
$("#ac1").on("change", function(){
    var sel = $(this);
    var val = sel.val();
    var data = sel.find("option:selected").data("val");
    button_5a1_list_submit(data, val);
});
```

This is a cross browser solution that will get the `part_one` (data-val) and the `part_two` (option value) when you make a selection from your `select` element.