# My onClick event is not setting "selectedValue" variable from user selected option?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a drop down box that is populated with city names. When the user clicks on/selects one of those city names, the value (or option) they clicked on gets set as the variable "selectedValue". It seems like my onClick event is not working properly, although i'm unsure of exactly what is going wrong.

```
    var selectValues = new Array(["Auckland"],["Christchurch"],["Dunedin"],["Hamilton"],["Tauranga"],["Wellington"],["Nelson"]);
    console.log("Pre-set select menu towns: " + selectValues);

    //creates _dropList as a select menu object with an ID and Class Name
    var _dropList = document.createElement("select"); {
        _dropList.id = "selectmenu";
        _dropList.className = "selectmenu";
    }

    //loops through the array "selectValues" and adds each value (town name) to the selectmenu as an option
    for ( var i = 0; i < selectValues.length; i++ ) {
        //creates a variable "_options"
        var _options = document.createElement("option");
        //"_options" is equal to the values of "selectValues" ("selectValues" values are added to the select menu)
        _options.value = selectValues[i];
        //debugging
        console.log("Select Menu Options: " + _options.value +" - Array Value: " + i);

        _options.innerHTML = selectValues[i];
        //appends the "selectValues" values (which are now equal to "_options" to the select menu)
        _dropList.appendChild(_options);
        //on click of the select menu option...
        _options.onClick = function() {
            //checks the value of the select menu and then 
            var check = _dropList.selectedIndex;
            //make a variable called "selectedValue" and assign it the value of the users chosen option
            var selectedValue = selectValues[check];
            //sends the value of "selectedValue" to the _checkNewTown function
            _checkNewTown(selectedValue);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `change` listener on `<select>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> onclick event on option tag will fail on most versions of IE, Safari and Chrome.
>
> Refer this question -> [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

```js
var selectValues = [
  ["Auckland"],
  ["Christchurch"],
  ["Dunedin"],
  ["Hamilton"],
  ["Tauranga"],
  ["Wellington"],
  ["Nelson"]
];
console.log("Pre-set select menu towns: " + selectValues);

//creates _dropList as a select menu object with an ID and Class Name
var _dropList = document.createElement("select");

_dropList.id = "selectmenu";
_dropList.className = "selectmenu";
_dropList.addEventListener('change', function() {
  _checkNewTown(this.value);
});

//loops through the array "selectValues" and adds each value (town name) to the selectmenu as an option
for (var i = 0; i < selectValues.length; i++) {
  //creates a variable "_options"
  var _options = document.createElement("option");
  //"_options" is equal to the values of "selectValues" ("selectValues" values are added to the select menu)
  _options.value = selectValues[i];
  //debugging
  console.log("Select Menu Options: " + _options.value + " - Array Value: " + i);

  _options.innerHTML = selectValues[i];
  //appends the "selectValues" values (which are now equal to "_options" to the select menu)

  //on click of the select menu option...

  _dropList.appendChild(_options);

  document.body.appendChild(_dropList);

}

function _checkNewTown(i) {
  document.getElementById('data').innerText = i;
}
```

```html
<div id='data'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the function by `addEventListener()`

```
//with onClick event
_dropList.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // code here for after select
);

//with onChange event
_dropList.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // code here for after select
);
```

```js
var selectValues = new Array(["Auckland"],["Christchurch"],["Dunedin"],["Hamilton"],["Tauranga"],["Wellington"],["Nelson"]);

console.log("Pre-set select menu towns: " + selectValues);

//creates _dropList as a select menu object with an ID and Class Name
var _dropList = document.createElement("select"); {
 _dropList.id = "selectmenu";
 _dropList.className = "selectmenu";
}

//loops through the array "selectValues" and adds each value (town name) to the selectmenu as an option
for ( var i = 0; i < selectValues.length; i++ ) {
 //creates a variable "_options"
 var _options = document.createElement("option");
 //"_options" is equal to the values of "selectValues" ("selectValues" values are added to the select menu)
 _options.value = selectValues[i];
 //debugging
 console.log("Select Menu Options: " + _options.value +" - Array Value: " + i);
  
 _options.innerHTML = selectValues[i];
 //appends the "selectValues" values (which are now equal to "_options" to the select menu)
 _dropList.appendChild(_options);
 document.body.appendChild(_dropList);
 //on click of the select menu option...
 _dropList.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //checks the value of the select menu and then 
  var check = _dropList.selectedIndex;
  //make a variable called "selectedValue" and assign it the value of the users chosen option
  var selectedValue = selectValues[check];
  //sends the value of "selectedValue" to the _checkNewTown function
  _checkNewTown(selectedValue);
  }
 );
}

function _checkNewTown(val){
 console.log('selcted val ' + val);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 </body>
</html>
```