# Browser failure or what?

Tags: javascript, html

I had create the following code

```
<script>
    function show()
    {
        document.getElementById("changetable").style.display = "initial";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function hide()
    {
        document.getElementById("changetable").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<select>
    <option onclick="hide()">1</option>
    <option onclick="hide()">2</option>
    <option onclick="hide()">3</option>
</select>
<input name="convert" id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Convert" size="10" onclick="return show();"/>
<div id="changetable" style="display:none" align="center">
    <table width="526" height="140" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <th>
                name:
            </th>
            <td>
                <input name="fname" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine, except when i using google chrome to display it.  The table is shown, but it cant be hide after i click the option value. Mozilla and others is totally working fine. Any idea?

Comment: You don't close the `div#changetable`

Comment: i did, forgot to add in sorry

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6m1bhj5n/

Comment: how do you introduce so many bugs when copying and pasting your test code?

Comment: @sevenseacat ignore the minor mistake, i changed a bit original code. back to the original problem.

Comment: @madalinivascu I wanted the content inside the `<option>` to function, not the `<select>`

Comment: @Juhana any idea to modify such coding?

Comment: Yes. Read the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem the `show()` function is not defined.

Comment: erm, it was my mistake, i edited the code, yet it still cant show.

Comment: It seems events on the option tag are broken at the current moment https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058960/5203655 I updated a bin http://jsbin.com/motojanawu/edit?html,output

Comment: @Sean They're not "broken", onclick events on options are not in the spec so they're not allowed.