# Why onClick not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

why onclick not working in chrome, this my code :

```
<select name="post_color" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">-Pilih-</option>
    <option onclick="GetColor(1)" value="1">Red</option>
    <option onclick="GetColor(2)" value="2">Black</option>
</select>

function GetColor(idc){
    $('#colorcategory').remove();
    utilsx.Color(idc);
};

var utilsx = {};
    (function ($) {

          $.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(textStatus);
              alert(errorThrown);
              alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

          }});

        utilsx.Color =  function Color(idc) {
            $("#colorf").append("<select id='colorcategory' name='post_color_cat' class='form-control'></select>");
            //alert(id);
            var data={idc:idc};
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                datatype:"html",
                url:"",
                data:data,
                cache:false,
                success: function(data) { 
                              $('#colorcategory').append(data);
                }
            });
        return false;
    };

    })(jQuery, window, document);
```

if i use in mozilla this code working and give url like this

```
http://localhost/test/color?idc=1&_=1452675443158
```

but in chrome no url and not give respone or anything.

how fix this?

Tahnk you

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome Please have a look at this.

Comment: Why you don't use change event on select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `change` event:

```
<select name="post_color" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">-Pilih-</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Black</option>
</select>

$("SELECT.form-control").change(function(){
    $('#colorcategory').remove();
    utilsx.Color($(this).val());
});
```

If you want to exclude value 0:

```
$("SELECT.form-control").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() > 0){
        $('#colorcategory').remove();
        utilsx.Color($(this).val());
    }
});
```