# This simple HTML code does not work on any browser, except mozilla. Why?

Tags: html, select

why does the following simple select button work on mozilla but not on chrome or safari. and when i say work i mean, the getHistory function gets called successfully on mozilla but not on other browsers.

```
<select id="history" style="width: 10%; margin-top: 150px; margin-left: 1200px;" >
  <option>History</option>
  <option onclick="getHistory(0.5);"> 2 weeks      </option>
  <option onclick="getHistory(1);">   1 month      </option>
  <option onclick="getHistory(3);">   3 months     </option>
  <option onclick="getHistory(6);">   6 months     </option>
  <option onclick="getHistory(0);">   Adam and Eve </option>
  <option onclick="getCurrent();">    Current      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Define "work" please? If it's the clicking of the options - it's wiser to use the select's `onchange` event and do the processing there.

Comment: the function getHistory doesnt get called.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript onclick doesn't work on **options** in IE and Chrome. You can refer this link for more detail: [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

You can bind value in options and fetch them on change event of select. Sample code below:

```
<select id="history" style="width: 10%; margin-top: 150px; margin-left: 1200px;" onchange="selectChangeEvent(this.value)">
  <option value="History">History</option>
  <option value="0.5">2 week</option>
  <option value="1">1 month</option>
  <option value="3">3 months</option>
  <option value="6">6 months</option>
  <option value="3">Adam and Eve </option>
  <option value="Current">Current</option>
</select>

//JavaScript code
function selectChangeEvent(_selectedVal) {
     if(_selectedVal == "Current") {
          getCurrent();
     }
     else {
          getHistory(_selectedVal);
     }
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer and close the question, if that is working for you.