# Trigger click on first option in select in angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

this is my select in html :

```
<select id="editProfileForm:AttributesList" 
              name="editProfileForm:AttributesList" 
              size="6" class="allLists" 
              [(ngModel)]="atr1"  >
   <option *ngFor="#attr of attributes"(click)="onSelect(attr, attr.domainDiscrete)">
        {{attr.name}}              
   </option>
</select>
```

this is my code in component :

```
onSelect(attclickname: Attribut, statusDiscret: boolean) 
 { 
 this.selectedAttr = attclickname; 
 this._discret = statusDiscret;

 }
```

when I click on the option elements (ie the attribute name), I get the operators and values of this attribute, I want the first option or click Default

Answer (score 0):

The `<option>` element doesn't fire a `click` event. You need to apply the `(click)` binding on the `<select>` element.

See also [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)