# Javascript code runs in Mozilla Firefox but not in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

This code runs perfectly in mozilla firefox but it does not run in google chrome. Help me how to make it run in google chrome. I want this same code to run in google chrome. Everything is working fine in firefox

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="class" class="form-control" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
  <option value="Choose...">Choose...</option>
  <option value="10th" onclick="myFunction()">10th</option>
  <option value="12th" onclick="myFunction1()">12th</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputSubjects3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Subjects</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Maths">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Maths
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Science">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Science
      </div><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv1" style="display:none;">
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Physics">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Physics
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Chemistry">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Chemistry
      </div><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit"><br><br>
</div>
```

I want the same code to run in google chrome. It is not working at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Chrome likes you trying to add a `click` listener to an `option` tag. Try adding a `change` listener instead - and add it properly with Javascript, if at all possible, rather than in an inline attribute (which is as bad as `eval`):

```js
document.querySelector('#inlineFormCustomSelect')
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    const { value } = this;
    if (value === '10th') myFunction();
    if (value === '12th') myFunction1();
  });

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
  var y = document.getElementById("mydiv");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="class" class="form-control" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
  <option value="Choose...">Choose...</option>
  <option value="10th">10th</option>
  <option value="12th">12th</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputSubjects3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Subjects</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Maths">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Maths
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Science">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Science
      </div><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit">
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv1" style="display:none;">
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Physics">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Physics
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Chemistry">
            <span class="slider"></span>
        </label> Chemistry
      </div><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit"><br><br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onClick evenet is not supported in chrome for select options.You should change onclick to onChange, then your code will work.

```
<select name="class" class="form-control" onChange="MyFunction();" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">


 <option value="Choose...">Choose...</option>
  <option value="10th">10th</option>
  <option value="12th">12th</option>

</select>
```