# issue with making a <select> box bringing you to another page

Tags: html, select

Hey guys so I am trying to create a quick search with the  boxes.  I thought I could just put in some  tags but does not work so I was wondering how I would go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="advancesearch">

                <div class="audio-quicksearch">
                    <select>
                    <a href="/mics"><option value="Microphones">Microphones</option></a>
                     <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div><!-- END #advancesearch -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use JavaScript `window.location`?

```
<div id="advancesearch">
    <div class="audio-quicksearch">
          <select>
             <option value="Microphones" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">Microphones</option>
             <option value=""></option>
             <option value=""></option>
             <option value=""></option>
           </select>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Or create a function

```
<div id="advancesearch">
   <div class="audio-quicksearch">
         <select>
            <option></option>
            <option value="Microphones" onclick="redirect_me('http://www.google.com');">Microphones</option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
<script>
   function redirect_me(re_link) {
   window.location = re_link;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing happens once I click.

Comment: @DavidBiga works for me... try adding an empty option tag before the microphone and than click on microphone option

Comment: Ya I did, does not work.  I don't know if it makes a difference but I am dev in wordpress

Comment: I don't have idea about wordpress, haven't worked on it, but I tested locally and it works...redirects me to google.com

Comment: :( well this stinks,  No other ideas?

Comment: @DavidBiga haha, well try making a function like..mmmm wait I'll edit my answer, doesn't make any difference but why don't give it a try

Comment: Sure.....ususally you can send it to in javascript and have it send you? or somfin.

Comment: oh you are doing wrong, you need the full path.. `onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'"`

Comment: @DavidBiga oh yes, I guess stack turned it into a link lol... this totally works, updated my answer, works with a function too..

Comment: Are you including a file in the header??

Comment: Ya dude nothing happens, just goes to value but no sending!

Comment: @DavidBiga I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MixolydianV/w8Qjk/) of Mr Alien's first answer - does it work for you? EDIT: actually, it doesn't entirely work for me - just refreshes the page. Probably to do with it being a fiddle though.

Comment: I added in the second example as well - see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MixolydianV/w8Qjk/1/)

Comment: @Jeff make an html file locally and see

Comment: @DavidBiga These both work for me when run from a local file. David: what browser are you using?

Comment: I'll just install chrome and see if that's the problem.

Comment: @DavidBiga oh dude you should've mentioned me about the chrome thing, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160943/onclick-doesnt-work-in-chrome

Comment: @DavidBiga Yeah, it's chrome that's the problem =/

Comment: @DavidBiga haha happy programming :)