# Link in a <select> with JS doesn't work on Chrome. IE & FF it works

Tags: javascript, html

one simple question:

Why this code works perfectly in FF and IE and in Chrome it doesn't?

```
<select  class="langbox" name="forma">
        <option class="text-option" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl/it'" >Italiano</option>
        <option class="text-option" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl/en'" >English</option>
        <option class="text-option" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl/de'" >Deutsch</option>
        <option class="text-option" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl/fr'" >Français</option>
        <option class="text-option" onClick="window.location = 'http://www.myurl/ru'" >Pусский </option>

    </select>
```

It doesn't redirect me on the url I want, it does nothing on Chrome. In Firefox and IE it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<select class="langbox" name="forma" onChange="window.location
                 ='http://www.myurl/'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option class="text-option" value="it">Italiano</option>
    <option class="text-option" value="en">English</option>
    <option class="text-option" value="de">Deutsch</option>
    <option class="text-option" value="fr">Fran&ccedil;ais</option>
    <option class="text-option" value="ru">Pусский</option>
</select>
```

You don't click on options, you change the select. While some browsers may be tolerant of this, others may not be (as you have discovered). Especially mobile browsers, which may have a completely different UI for `<select>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at this:
[Onclick doesn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160943/onclick-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

```
<select class="input" onchange="window.location.href = this.value" style="width:200px">
    <option>---</option>
    <option value="http://www.myurl/it">Italiano</option>
    <option value="http://www.myurl/en">English</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to not use onClick by using JQuery.
Try this:

```
$('.text-option').click(function() {
    var loc = $(this).val();
    window.location = loc;
});
```

Just set the `value=""` of each select and put in the URL.

I think this solution should work in all browsers.

Comment: -1 for pointless jQuery. You're still trying to click an `<option>` element!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm not forcing him to use JQuery, and my solution does solve the problem if implemented, so I don't see the reason for a -1. I even upvoted your answer because it was better.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "`window.location.href`" instead of "`window.location`" it works for Chrome